# D3 image transition of height only

Tags: d3.js, transition

I am trying to work with D3 transitions and an image and I seem to be having trouble.

I am trying to cause the image to disappear by having the top and bottom of the image close together until it gets to the middle, like a shutter effect, or erasing lines from the top and bottom until it is all gone. I don't want the image to scale at all, I just want it to close.

So far I have gotten the image to scale down to 0, but that is not what I want.

Also on the first transition it drops the image to the middle of the box before it starts the transition, whats up with that?

http://jsfiddle.net/Qda6B/

```
var svgContainer = d3.select("#box").append("svg")
.style("width", '100%')
.style("height", '100%')
.style("background-color","blue");

var imgs = svgContainer.append("svg:image")
.attr("xlink:href", "http://guiaavare.com/img/upload/images/Aishwarya-Rai-face.jpg")
.attr("width", "400")
.attr("height", "400");

d3.select("#inbutton").on("click", function () {
imgs
    .attr("height",400)
    .transition()
    .attr({
        height: 0,
        y: 200
    })
    .duration(500);
});

d3.select("#outbutton").on("click", function () {
imgs
    .transition()
    .attr({
        height: 400,
        y: 0
    })
    .duration(500);
});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve the effect you are after using `clipPath`: http://jsfiddle.net/Qda6B/5/

```
var clipRect = svgContainer.append('svg:defs')
                .append('svg:clipPath')
                .attr('id', 'shutter-clip')
                .append('rect')
                .attr({
                    x: 0,
                    y: 0,
                    height: 400,
                    width: 400
                })


var imgs = svgContainer.append("svg:image")
    // ...
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#shutter-clip)");
```

And then doing the `transitions` on the `height` of the `rect` inside the `clipPath`.

---

As an aside, though this is possible to do with `d3`, this very likely belongs in the domain of CSS3 transitions or jQuery or GASP animations.

Comment: Nice! I was starting to approach this by manipulating the SVG container, which seemed rather draconian. Up-voted.